# Using a class as library

Tags: java

I'm doing lately so much C++ that I forgot how to use Java. I'm confused with the includes of C++ what Java doesn't have. I've googled but always finds something like import but that doesn't work and making an object but this isn't possible because it's a library.

I've got a class A : with something like this:

```
class Library
{
  int findMaximum(int [] table)
  {
    int max = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
    {
      if( table[i] > max )
        max = table[i];
    }
    return max;
  }
}
```

and so much more functions.

And I've got a class B:

```
class Tdd_1{

  static boolean test1(){

  int [] table = new int[20];

  for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
    table[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100)+1;

  findMax(table);

  return true;
  }
}
```

Now I can't use findmax in that class? How can I fix this? The files are in the same dir?

Then eventually the purpose is to have one main file like:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    System.out.println("Test 1: \n");
    if(test1())
      System.out.println("Passed.\n");
    else
      System.out.println("Failed.\n");
  }
```

where I can run test1 and all the others....

Can someone help me?

Kind regards;

What is a test case where I can

Comment: I suggest you make your method `static` use an IDE as it will do the rest.

Comment: in JDK6 you can use `import static Tdd_1.test1;` but I'm unsure whether this works in JDK 1.5.  You will need to make the method public afair.

Comment: Judging from the problem you're having, you're doing C, not C++. I suggest reading an introduction to OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate The Library class first before you can invoke its methods.

```
Library lib = new Library();
.
.
.
lib.findMaximum(table);
```

Or declare `findMaximum` as static like so:

```
static int findMaximum(int [] table)
```

and access it like so:

```
Library.findMaximum(table)
```

Comment: Just like riding a bike, it'll come back to you!!

Answer (score 1):

Declare the method public static:

```
public static int findMaximum(int [] table)
```

Then call it like this:

```
Library.findMaximum(table);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `findMax()` is static then you can call it with `Library.findMax()`.

Otherwise make a `new Library()` object and call it on the object.

For **TDD** I recommend using a test library such as JUnit rather than calling your tests from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You must use inheritance (by using `extends` keyword) if you want to use `Library`'s `findMaximum` method in java, like so:

```
class Tdd_1 extends Library {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an object of Library class and call findMaximum method, `new Library().findMaximum(table)` or make that method static and call it by class name. Library.findMaximum(table)